# React : best way to inject Component in dynamically loaded HTML?

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

I'm new on React (I more at ease w/ jQuery or AngularJS). I have a special case and I don't find a good way to resolve it...

My app contains an area which is like a "document viewer". It loads an HTML content from the backend (via API, using Fetch) and inject it in the "viewer" component. The HTML content loaded looks like an "university report" (it's just a formatted text, only `<span>` and `<p>` with `class="..."` attributes, nothing more).
Ex : `<p>Lorem ispum <span>some text</span> loreb bis <span>ipsum</span></p> ...`

I load the content, and inject it this way in the `render()` of my component `<Viewer>` : 
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ getFreshlyLoadedHTML() } />`

Easy, it works just fine !

But... Now, I want to inject some "interactive" components in the loaded HTML. For example, some button to give a feedback etc. The API must decide where to place the component between the words/nodes of the formatted text (HTML).
Ex : 
`<p> Lorem ispum <span>some text</span> 
loreb bis <span>ipsum</span>
<MyFeedbackButton paragraph="1.3"/>
</p><p>Other Lorem Ipsum<p><span>...</span>`

There, I'm stucked because I cannot use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` if there are components inside the loaded HTML...

First attempt : I've tried modifying the API, and instead of sending the HTML in a string to the app, I send a custom JSON structure that represents almost the final JSX structure that I want. Then, in my react page, the render function only have to parse the JSON and build the JSX (here, a JsFiddle example if it's not clear : https://jsfiddle.net/damienfa/69z2wepo/34536/ )

It works, but I can't believe it's the good way...

I see a major problem : all the HTML node (span, p...) that I build from the render function are referenced by reactJs, is it really necessary ? Mostly, there are "dead" nodes (I mean, dom node that won't never changed, this is static formatted text).

Just take a look a all those "data-reactid" on nodes that never will be interactive...
[image: react problem]

What would be your advice on that case ?

What about my attempt with a JSON-structure sent by the API ?

Is there a way to say to react "do not reference that element" ?

Do you clearly see a better solution to my problem ?

Comment: I think its a sensible option to send JSON that can be coverted into JSX, the major problem you mention with that solution is actually a part of React and I don't think it's actually a major problem? Other than a very minor performance issue I don't think it would be a big problem

Comment: I agree with @Geraint, don't worry about the overhead, it's most likely negligible. But do you need to get the content as HTML, and is it also necessary to add buttons in between the fetched contents?

Answer (score 0):

Your current workflow is not very secure and subject to many potential errors and open doors, especially concerning code injection ...

The overload due to react tracking the nodes is not an issue, React could track 10 000 nodes and not have a problem (well actually on many of my apps React has more than 100 000 nodes to care about and it still rurns perfectly).

I see different solutions here:

1. If there are only 3 or 4 possibilities of dynamic components and order, you might have components like "templates" to which you would simple send text arguments. This is the safest and easiest option.
2. If it doesn't suit your use-case but the JSON file can contain only a limited set of components, the components should be located in your main app, and then rendered with custom props from the JSON. Actually given the structure of data you could consider using xml instead of json and build a xml tree that you would parse and render. Only components from your white list would be rendered and it would limit drastically the potentials security issues. If needs quite some work on the XML parser though.
3. If the JSON file can contain many many different and unpredictable components or if the behaviour of those components is largely dynamic and independant of your app, you might as well consider using an iframe, with its own JS and HTML, so that this part of the code is isolated from the rest.

Comment: Thanks @Mijamo ! It's true, there's only 2 possibilities of dynamic components, more the '<p>' and `<span>` nodes. So, I will think about your solution 1. Have you seen the JsFiddle I give ? What is the difference with the solution you propose ? 
About the 2nd solution, I'm not sure to understand why I would need to use an XML instead ? Parsing XML is a pain in front-end js... (But I admit XML is more coherent view of my data structure).

About, code injection, how is it possible? In my JsFiddle I have a little white list of tag, and I suggest to "sanitize" the string (removing links etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try using an inline anonymous function within the inner content from within React using JSX.  It works!  Just be careful about how you wire up the data so there isn't a route where a user can inject HTML from an input or text field.

`<div className="html-navigation-button">{(() =>
  {
      const CreateMarkup = ( sNavItemName :string ) => {
          return {__html: sNavItemName };
      }
      var sTextToAddHtmlTo = props.nextNavItem.name.toString();
      sTextToAddHtmlTo = sTextToAddHtmlTo.replace( "/", "/<wbr>" );
      return (
           <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={CreateMarkup( sTextToAddHtmlTo )} > 
           </div> 
        );
    })()}
 </div>`

- I didn't override the React internals of 'render()', but only used a React Component with props wiring to pass down data to it for rendering.
- I added the hook for 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' deep within the return content of the React Component so there would be no easy way to intercept and manipulate it.
- As such, there is no 100% guarantee on safety, but that's where adding good security to web services, databases, and use of CORS and CORB would be helpful to lock down security risks.